# Which stars can I travel to?

Tags: master-of-orion-2

Once I select a ship, I can't send to any star, only certain stars. The rule seems to be that I can't travel more than a certain distance from the nearest colony or outpost. Scouts seem to be able to go farther than other ships. What distance can I travel, exactly? What are the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's based on your refuelling range, which starts out at 4 parsecs with the Standard Fuel Cell technology and goes up with further fuel cell technological advances.  The refuelling range prevents you from travelling to any destination that's not in the given range of one your colonies or outposts.  However, it doesn't directly limit the distance your ships can travel. For example, a ship can always travel between two of your colonies regardless of the distance between them.

Scout ships can travel farther, an additional 50%, because they're outfitted with Extended Fuel Tanks. It's possible to add this system to other ship designs, but because of the large amount of space it takes it's generally only useful for scouts.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the distance between two stars in parsecs other than putting a ship at star A and hovering the mouse over star B?

Comment: @JackM Not that I know of, though you usually don't care unless you have a ship at star A. You can however find out if a planet is in range of your colonies or not by viewing the list of planets and filtering by "Planets in Range".